# How to calculate $N! \mod P$ fast?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, programming

Given numbers $N$ and $P$. Calculate $\:N! \mod P$.

$N$ and $P$ are very large so that I can't calculate it by using *Fermat's little theorem* directly.

But $|N - P|$ is small($\le 1000$) so I can solve it by using *Wilson's theorem*.

When $N < P$, $$(\prod_{i = n + 1}^{P - 1}{i})^{-1} \times (P - 1)\mod\ P$$ is the answer.

And I want to know how I can solve it faster when $|N - P|$ gets larger.

Thanks.

Comment: This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962) may be of interest.

Comment: You can use factorial algorithms that use half the number of multiplications to get $N!$.

Comment: If this would work efficiently for every pair $(N/P)$ , we would have an efficient way to factor $P$ , so there is probably no general efficient way.

Comment: Competitive programming explanation: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/factorial-modulo.html it only matters for N much larger than P.  FWIW there are fast ways to compute ${n \choose m} \pmod p$